# Is there any way to access couchDB url used in IBM blockchain cloud?

Tags: couchdb-futon, ibm-blockchain

I have deployed an instance of Blockchain database in IBM cloud. It uses hyperledger fabric 1.2.1 and couchDB as a database. Is there any way to access the couchDB web based administration console?

Comment: I am not much familiar with IBM cloud ways but the url to access couchdb web console is `http://<host_address_of_couchdb>:<port>/_utils`. By default, the port for couchdb will be `5984` in hyperledger fabric.

Comment: I am not able to find the host address of couchdb for the IBM blockchain cloud application.